# Creating a NuGet package that includes other Nuget Packages - NewtonSoft Reference Errors

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget

Getting started with creating NuGet packages for various common libraries, that were up to now typically added as a project to a solution.

Using TFS 2017 to build and deploy the NuGet packages to the Package Manager built into TFS 2017.

I have an issue with dependencies and don't fully understand how to resolve it. It's also a little complicated to detail; so here goes.

- I have built a class library that has a NuGet package installed - The package is SharpRaven 2.2.0
- SharpRaven has a dependency on NewtonSoft.Json >= 6.0.8
- This results in Newtonsoft.Json being added to my class library. By default NewtonSoft.Json 6.0.8 is installed.
- I then package up my class library as a NuGet package - Called it TestNuGet
- TFS is building the nuget by using the .csproj file and not the nuspec

When I use this new package in projects I see there are dependencies for SharpRaven and Newtonsoft (if neither of those are currently installed in the project).

My problem starts with Newtonsoft.Json.

Take the following projects:

**Solution A and B**
 - Already has Newtonsoft 9.0.1.
 - Install TestNuGet, so SharpRaven is also added
 - Project is fine, no errors when using TestNuGet

**Solution C**
 - Already has Newtonsoft 9.0.1.
 - Install TestNuGet, so SharpRaven is also added
 - Errors when calling TestNuGet; error below:

**Solution C**
 - Remove Newtonsoft 9.0.1
 - Install TestNuGet, SharpRaven and Newtonsoft 6.0.8 installed
 - Project is fine. No errors
 - Update Newtonsoft
 - Get Errors again as before

If i update NewtonSoft to 9.0.1 in TestNuget and rebuild it I get exactly the same issues above.

There are no projects within Solution C that are referencing anything other than 9.0.1.

It seems to me that when adding a NuGet package NuGet looks at all of the packages within and uses those dependencies, ignoring what is already added to the TestNuget.

---

**So the question**, *i think* - Is there a way to instruct nuget to use the newtonsoft version i added to TestNuget and to not try and meet the dependency sharpraven is calling for? Something to add to the Packages.config perhaps?

Would I be better using a nuspec file? is there more that can be set in this to control how the package is built?

Or is there something I'm missing in my usage of these packages.

---

Error being thrown when trying to use the package is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Binding Redirect from the web.config of the solution that will not run looks as this:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I also tried adjusting the redirect to encapsulate 9.0.1

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.1.0" newVersion="9.0.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the actual error? Anyway it seems like you're running into the often-criticized default of installing the lowest common version of dependencies, which is an option in the NuGet client in Visual Studio which you could try setting to "highest".

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, sorry - just added it. Ref that setting, i'll go check that now, thanks!

Comment: @CodeCaster - So i rebuilt the TestNuGet using that setting; so adding SharpRaven installed Newtonsoft 10.0.2. I then added TestNuGet with that same setting. Still have the same error as above.

Comment: @Darren what types of projects are your Solution A-C? apps or libraries? do you use the PackageReference style nuget management or packages.config?

Comment: @MartinUllrich - I've used the nuget in 2 web solutions and 2 class libraries installed as windows services. It's failing on a web solution. I'm using the packages.config; I set TFS to use the csproj rather than the nuspec - seemed easier than maintaining a list of files/depedency nodes.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - I've just tried using SharpRaven in the solution thats failing, removed my nuget package and tried to use sharpRaven directly and get the same newtonsoft error - unless i install 6.0.8 specifically.

Comment: @Darren are there binding redirects generated to app.config / web.config? if not, try the solution from my answer.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - Thanks for your continued help. There are. I'll add them to the Q. AdmittedlyI know very little about this level of configuration.

Comment: @MartinUllrich - I feel ashamed.... we had the bindingRedirect in place though its parent assemblyBinding was targetting .net 2.5 - we're running 4.5

Comment: Added a note to my answer about that :) Glad you found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that an assembly has a reference to a version 6 of NewtonSoft.Json which is not found at runtime since only a higher version is present.

This is usually worked around with binding redirects. NuGet should automatically generate the necessary binding redirects into runnable (exe, web apps) projects using `packages.config` when installing packages.

For `PackageReference` based projects it is sometimes (test projects, plugin-library, …) required to also tell msbuild to automatically generate the needed binding redirects based on the resolved assemblies. This can be done by adding this to the `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However this does not protect against actual breaking changes that could have occurred in new major versions of a library.

Also note that these binding redirects may be overwritten by the binding redirects of other applications re-using the built assembly (parent projects, plugin-system etc).

Comment: Answer was in the final sentence of this answer. Thanks!